# F5 BigIp 1600 system restore via USB issue

Tags: f5

I just got home 2 of F5 Big ip 1600 and both have the same problem, TMOS should be reinstalled on new hard drives. I've downloaded OS version 12.1.2 and created boot USB thumb drive then followed F5 guide [eK13117](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13117).

According to this guide, as I understood, on reboot, appliance should be capable to start from USB, but nothing happens and there are no led blinking on USB drive. I suppose that ports USB were disabled somehow.

I also tried to enter BIOS [Change boot order](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K9599) with this procedure to see if I can enable USB back, but wasnt able to open it. Maybe some one worked with these boxes already and could help me to restore them by providing detailed procedure on how to at least to enter in BIOS settings?

p.s. I'm using [serial connection](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K7683) with Putty.

Comment: Have you tried another (quality) USB stick? Some of those cheap things are just crap.

Comment: Kingston, sony, sandisk thumb drives, external ide cd to usb box, external lenovo think usb dvd drive.